# Как с помощью оператора when реализовать выборку из строки по слову

Tags: android, kotlin

Условно говоря, у меня есть фраза "Каждый охотник желает знать где сидит фазан" и мне нужно реализовать оператор when так, чтобы из всей строки к каждому слову из этого предложения соответствовал определенный цвет. Каждый - RED, охотник - ORANGE...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Довольно сложно понять как именно вы будете использовать when, в плане передачи аргумента. Поэтому могу предложить составляющие этапы для решения вашей задачи. Вот есть у нас стринг:

```
val str = "Каждый охотник желает знать где сидит фазан"
```

дальше мы его делим на слова:

```
val words = str.split(" ")
```

на выходе будет `List<String>`:

```
[Каждый, охотник,...]
```

дальше чтобы получить первую букву используем метод `.first()`:

```
words[0].first()
```

и на выходе вы получаете:

```
К
```

можем получить буквы в цикле:

```
for(word in words){
   print(word.first())
}
```

дальше можно сделать метод куда вы будете передавать ваши буквы:

```
fun someMethod(letter:Char):String{
   return when(char){
          'К'-> "Красный"
           ...
           else->{"Error"}   
 
   }
}
```

ну и в цикле используем:

```
for(word in words){
       print(someMethod(word.first()))
}
```

я просто не знаю где вы это планируете использовать, поэтому не могу привязаться к предметной области :)

Comment: Спасибо большое за ответ, я сделал уже. Я учу язык Котлин и практическое задание было сделать выборку из предложения с помощью оператора when.  Я сделал ее с помощью in это я и хотел узнать =)

Answer (score 0):

Насколько я понимаю вам нужна следующая логика:

```
private fun getColor(query: String) = when (query) {
    "Каждый" -> R.color.red
    "охотник" -> R.color.orange
    "желает" -> R.color.yellow
    "знать" -> R.color.green
    "где" -> R.color.blue
    "сидит" -> R.color.darkBlue
    "фазан" -> R.color.violet
    else -> R.color.transparent
}
```